# :empty not working properly to hide field with no content

Tags: html, css

I am using the following code to display two buttons:

```html
<div class="row readmorewrapper">
 <div class="col-sm-5 readmorebutton">
    <h6 class="mtn mbn readmore"><a href="[wpv-post-url]">Read more</a></h6>
  </div>
 <div class="col-sm-5 purchasebutton">
    <h6 class="mtn mbn readmore">[types field='amazon-url' title='Purchase' target='_blank'][/types]</h6>   
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to hide `.purchasebutton` using `:empty` if the custom field has no content, but `.purchasebutton:empty` is not working. Am I using `:empty` incorrectly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The div with class "purchasebutton" is not empty. It contains an h6 element.

[From MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty)

"The :empty CSS pseudo-class represents any element that has no children. Children can be either element nodes or text (including whitespace). Comments or processing instructions do not affect whether an element is considered empty or not."

Comment: Is there another practice I can implement to hide the div what there is no content present in the custom field?

Comment: I do not know what your custom field is, but you may want to look at using a JavaScript if statement. I would probably hide the div by default, then use the following logic to show it: if customField is not empty, show the div